# Refactoring Entities with common fields but with different @JoinColumn parameters

Tags: jpa-2.0, mappedsuperclass, joincolumn

I have several entities that have same fields which are common to many tables. But those fields are not linked with the same parameter name in the relational tables(see object_1 and object_2 in the attached image).

I creacted an abstract class (IGlobalObject) and I used @MappedSuperclass to link it to subclass. Now I have to override parameters but I don't know how to do it ?

Please see the attached image for more details . [image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/AssociationOverrides.html

Comment: Thank you  @JBNizet